# Magento 2.4.2: How to stop a specific category page from being crawled?

Tags: magento2.4

Here’s the category page link:  https://www.perfectmakeupmirrors.com/light-bulbs-and-parts.html
I want it to appear in the site menu and be available to users. I just don’t want it crawled.Where in Magento can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the meta robots NOINDEX tag to your header. You have to use a module for this, because this is not a magento feature. [I use this module.](https://github.com/Web200/magento-seo)

Comment: Philippe, thanks. Could you please tell me where to start once I install this module from github on the server?

Comment: After install the module by running this command in project root
$ composer require "web200/magento-seo"
You have to run the setup:upgrade command
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade
Then, you will find the module settings in the magento admin: Store > Configuration > General > Search Engine Optimization

In production mode, you have to compile and deploy your content wit setup:di:compile and setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is very helpful. Is there no way to manually add just a single line in the head for this like the last solution in the article below from Magento forum suggests?

Comment: Philippe, here is the article I spoke about. https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-PWA-Theming-Layout/how-to-setup-noindex-follow-in-a-static-page/td-p/26721

Answer (score 0):

You can use the design configuration to update the rule,
See here for command https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: I read the article partially, and find it difficult to achieve my aim. Could you please give me an example of how to noindex?

Answer (score 0):

You can install this free extension: https://github.com/TidycodeIT/magento2-meta-robots